# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, reportviewer

I am getting this error that is related to ReportsViewer. I need to **eliminate all references** to this library. So where do I need to start deleting the references?

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Look at your page directives and the bin directory for a Report file. Then look in your web.config. Your app should compile fine after that.